# Getting an error when I try to add variable on Query on my php 7 platform

Tags: mariadb, php-7.2

I'm trying add limit  & offset as variables on a sql in php application

code looks like this:

```
$bind[':limit'] = $limit;
$bind[':offset'] = $offset;

$sql= 'SELECT id, monkeys '.
      'from monkeyisland mi ' .
      'left join monkeyland ml '
      'on mi.id = ml.id ' .
      'LIMIT :limit OFFSET :offset ';

$result = $query->run($sql,$bind);
```

the error message saying:

syntax error  check Mariadb server version for the right syntax
to use near ''100' OFFSET '0''

is there a different way to right this query variables? Thanks for help in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why are you using bind?
you can add the variables directly

```
$sql= 'SELECT id, monkeys '.
  'from monkeyisland mi ' .
  'left join monkeyland ml '
  'on mi.id = ml.id ' .
  'LIMIT ' .$limit. ' OFFSET ' .$offset;

$result = $query->run($sql);
```

The above query should return the same values of the variables!